# How can I export a datagridview to a Excel in c#?, I have an error

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

Below is the code :

```
private void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
{
   SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
   fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
   if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
       aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
       libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
       hoja_trabajo = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

       for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
           {
               hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
           }
       }
       libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName, 
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
       libros_trabajo.Close(true);
       aplicacion.Quit();
    }
}
```

Its works fine, with few data's, but when I use it with a lot more, the program stop working and say this:

```
No se controló COMException
Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800AC472
```

In this part:

```
for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
{
   //PROBLEM// hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();//PROBLEM
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: Can you please show your error in English?

Answer (score 0):

Create One Page Without Master Page Integration (In case if you are using Master Page in Asp.Net).

Then Bind all the Stuff on Page Load Event to grid Which ever Data You Required and Add This

```
public void CerateExcel()
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Name.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        form1.RenderControl(hw); //form1 it's name of you .aspx page (a form name with runat='server' tag)

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```